# jg not working properly in asm

Tags: assembly, nasm

```
section .data
msg db 'Largest number :: '
len equ $ - msg
num1 dd '47'
num2 dd '51'
num3 dd '22'

section .bss
largest resb 2

section .text
global _start

_start:

mov ecx, [num1]
cmp ecx, [num2]
jg check_third
mov ecx, [num2]
check_third:

cmp ecx, [num3]
jg _exit
mov ecx, [num3]

_exit:
mov [largest], ecx

mov edx, len
mov ecx, msg
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80

mov edx, 2
mov ecx, largest
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80

mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

answer is coming out to be 47 while it must come out to be 51

Comment: `largest` needs to be 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your numbers as a bunch of strings. Remove the quotes to get the comparisons right:

```
num1 dd 47
num2 dd 51
num3 dd 22
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to convert the result to a string when you want to print it.

---

To understand why it doesn't make sense to have the numbers as strings, consider how those strings are stored in memory: `'51`' consists of the character sequence `'5','1'` (i.e. `'5'` is stored before `'1'`, because it's the first character of the string). `'5','1'` is the same as `0x35,0x31`, which is the same as `0x3135`.
If we view `'47'` the same way we get `0x3734`, and now it should be clear that `cmp` on these isn't going to work.

Comment: so what must be the solution according to you?

Comment: What I said in my answer: _"Remove the quotes to get the comparisons right"_ and _"you'll have to convert the result to a string when you want to print it"_. And as a commenter noted, _"`largest` needs to be 4 bytes"_.

Comment: Making largest 4 bytes is not working as well, your earlier solutions sounds good and I believe it will work but I can't find a way to convert two digit number to string as a single digit number can be converted by adding '0'. But how to do it for a two digit number.